# Как разница между константой класса PDO FETCH_LAZY и остальными FETCH_...?

Tags: php, pdo

Как я понимаю `FETCH_LAZY` можно использовать тогда, когда нужно вернуть только некоторые поля? 
Прошу разъяснить данную ситуацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот [толковое разъяснение](http://www.php.su/functions/?pdostatement-fetch) констант функции **PDOStatement::fetch** для первого параметра( **fetch_style** ). Как не трудно понять:

```
PDO_FETCH_LAZY: combines PDO_FETCH_BOTH and PDO_FETCH_OBJ...
```

**Комбинирует две константы:**

```
PDO_FETCH_BOTH: returns an array indexed by both column name and column number as returned in your result set

PDO_FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set
```

Почитайте информацию, приведенную в ссылке, да и поймете, чем отличаются друг от друга константы типа `PDO_FETCH_*`. Константа  `PDO_FETCH_LAZY` всего лишь объединяет две другие.

Comment: все равно недопонимаю, по ссылке вижу что фак просто передрали с php.net, ничего нового я там не увидел, хотелось бы понять что к чему на "живом" примере, т.е. в какой ситуации можно воспользоваться LAZY, а когда уже лучше исп. другие константы.

Comment: Почивший в бане Asen пропустил один момент: 

     creating the object variable names as they are accessed

Из-за того, что имена переменных объекта создаются по мере доступа к ним, fetch и назван ленивым (LAZY)